# Which module do I load to enable PHP on Apache 2.4 on Windows Server?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to run PHP 5.6 on Apache 2.4. I installed Apache 2.4 as a service on Windows Server 2012.

I downloaded and installed [Apache 2.4.20 Win64](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/). Then I downloaded [php 5.6.23 VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe binaries](http://windows.php.net/download/)

The last step that is needed to load php module in Appache to use php.

`LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"`

The problem is that the file php5apache2_4.dll is not found with the php binaries.

What is the correct file that I should use to load `php5_module`

here is a list of the content of the php binaries

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason you got the non-thread-safe (NTS) version? The NTS version does not include the Apache module on purpose.

Anyways, you can download the thread-safe (TS) version and put the DLL into your NTS PHP folder. I've never tried this so you might just get more errors. The NTS version is meant for FastCGI environments.

If you have no rhyme or reason for picking NTS then just get the TS version.

Please read the **Choose Build** section of http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php

Comment: Thank you very much. There is no good reason why I picked NTS other than I saw that it is the recommended for windows. I just downloaded the TS version and sure enough the `php5apache2_4.dll` file is there. But now Apache is not starting. I get a generic windows error when I try to run the service. The Apache error log is empty.

Comment: @Jaylen Try adding two more lines to your conf file: `PHPIniDir "C:/php"` and `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` after the `LoadModule` line

Comment: I have but sill the same error. This is exactly what I added `LoadModule php5_module "C:/php v/php-5.6.23-Win32-VC11-x86/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php v/php-5.6.23-Win32-VC11-x86"`

Comment: @Jaylen The Apache error log should definitely be telling you at least something. Is your `LogLevel notice` configured like I've written? I would check the Windows Event Viewer under `Windows Logs->Application` and `Windows Logs->System` for additional clues.

Comment: @Jaylen You downloaded Apache 64-bit, you should download 64-bit PHP as well

Comment: is it recommended to use 64bit php or is that still a testing thing in PHP?

Comment: @Jaylen Also, why are you sticking to PHP 5.6? [**It will be obsolete quite soon**](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). I definitely recommend PHP 7 because it literally decreased my processing times by 30-50%. I have a PDF process which takes 7 seconds on PHP 5.6 and now it takes just 4 seconds.

Comment: 64-bit is extremely safe and stable. Make sure to get 64-bit MySQL as well

Comment: I actually ended up changing everything to 32 bit. Thank you very much for your help